# jquery animation and float not floating

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, css-float

I have two images I want to be stuck together for lack of a better term.  As the image on the left animates off the screen, the right image just sits there not moving.  I have tried to use position: relative; in the CSS for the right-hand image and even tried to animate it by adding to the javascript (see comments in the js file) but it didn't change anything.

**The HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slidetest01.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="./javascripts/picslider01a.js"></script>
</HEAD>

<BODY onload="picrotate()">
<div id="slideshow"><img id="picshown" src="./pix/mtn01.jpg">
<img id="pichidden" src="./pix/mtn02.jpg"></div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

**The CSS**

```
#slideshow {
position: relative;
left:0px;
top:0px;
width: 1200px;
float: left;
}

#picshown {
position: relative;
float: left;
}

#pichidden {
float: left;
}
```

**The javascript**

```
function picrotate () {
var picts = new Array();
picts[0] = "./pix/mtn01.jpg";
picts[1] = "./pix/mtn02.jpg";
picts[2] = "./pix/mtn03.jpg";
picts[3] = "./pix/mtn04.jpg";
picts[4] = "./pix/mtn05.jpg";

var count = 2;

function rotator() {

$("#picshown").animate({left: "-600px"});
//Tried adding $("#pichidden").animate({left: "0px"}); here but did not work
//Need to delay since the rest triggers immediately after transition starts.
setTimeout(function () {    //1 second should be enough time for the slide.

count = (count+1)%5;

var discard = document.getElementById("picshown");  //removes old picture
discard.parentNode.removeChild(discard);

document.getElementById("pichidden").setAttribute("id", "picshown");    //makes current picture the active one

ith = document.createElement("img");    //create a new image
ith.id = "pichidden";
ith.src = picts[count];

$("#slideshow").append(ith);//Append it to the slideshow
}, 1000);

}   //end rotator

setInterval(rotator, 2000);
}   // end picrotate
```

Comment: Use `marginLeft: "-600px"` instead of `left`.

Comment: And don't be afraid to use `var picts = ["./pix/mtn01.jpg","./pix/mtn02.jpg","./pix/mtn03.jpg"]`;

Comment: Don't be afraid to use `count = (count+1)%picts.length;` I mean, make you code more modular and easier to modify in the future. Use JS to calculate stuff.

Comment: `$("#slideshow")` inside a loop is a bad idea, cache your selector inside a variable and use that variable instead!

Comment: why you're using `document.getElementById("picshown");` when you clearly use jQuery?

Comment: Works beautifully.  Why did this work instead of "left"?

Comment: `left` is interpreted when the element has an absolute or relative positionning, but not when it is static (default). `margin-left` can be used on any element.

Comment: To answer a lot of these questions, I have just started with jQuery and wanted to get a working product and then go back and clean/tighten it up.  And Roko you are absolutely right that I should have passed a variable to the loop.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan He did not mention any relative position in the code he posted first. But now he does. When you change an element's positionning (absolute or relative), it affects the element itself, but not the elements around it, it's "out of the flow". But when you use margin-left, the flow adapts to it, hence, the next image will move as well.